# Problem with including files with folders in PHP

Tags: php, include

I was trying to organize my project so that it would be easier to detect problems.

I started with `layout` folders containing the layout pages, like `header.php`. This includes CSS, metadata, footer, and JS scripts. But I can't include it in other pages using the following instruction:

```
include 'layout/header.php';
```

Instead I have to write this:

```
<?php 
include ("layout/header.php");
include 'header.php';
?>
```

I'm afraid this could be a bad practice and that could cause a bug in my website later. Any help with this?

Comment: If `layout` is a subdirectory of the directory containing the main script, the first way should work.

Comment: Please show how your project is organized.